# Why doesnt my dropdown menu work?

Tags: css

The dropdown menu doesnt work. When I remove the function "display:none" the UL in the submenu shows, then I add the a:hover, display:block, it goes away, but when I hover over it, the submenu does show. why?

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">> om oss</a></li>
        <li><a href="page/vad.html">> vad vi gör</a></li>
        <li><a href="page/retorik.html">> vad är retorik?</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice four</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="sidor/weekend.html">> storytelling</a></li>
        <li><a href="sidor/fq.html">> kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    background-color: #8D8084;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 12px;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline;
}
#nav a {
}
#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin: -12px;
    background: #8D8084;
    font-family: Candara, "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav ul li.active a {
    background-color: #A4999D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #A4999D;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing an `li` tag too soon:

```
<li><a href="page/retorik.html">> vad är retorik?</a></li> <!-- this shouldn't close here -->

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sevice one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sevice two</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">Sevice three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sevice four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Fix

```
<li>
    <a href="page/retorik.html">> vad är retorik?</a>     
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sevice one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sevice two</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Sevice three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sevice four</a></li>
    </ul>    
</li><!--  it should close here -->
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! But now I have a new problem. The dropmenu should show up under it not next to it.

Comment: @SabaaAlkatib have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/by0fmd4o/ it should give you an idea of how to position the sub menu underneath. If you continue to have issues just ask another question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The above code will try to find a child `ul` elements on hover. There is no child `ul` element in your code. It is siblings element. Update your code like below.

```
  #nav ul li:hover + ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the tag at right place
insted of

```
<li><a href="page/retorik.html">> vad är retorik?</a></li>

        <ul>
```

it should be

```
<li><a href="page/retorik.html">> vad är retorik?</a>

        <ul>
......insert dropdown here
        </ul>
</li>
```

Here is a working Codepen that i created
http://codepen.io/Prashantsani/pen/tIfqb

Also, you cant put any tag as a direct child of a `<ul>`Tag. 
`<ul>`  or `<ol>` can only have a `<li>`  as a direct child. 
In your html you have inserted a `<ul>`  after closing `</li>` , Thus making the dropdown `<ul>` a direct child of `<ul>` .